# React.memo is not working, when only Parent component changes, children component still render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react.memo

**Problem:**

Children component is exported with React.memo(), with the intention of **not** rendering children component when only parent component is updating. However, when parent component updates, the children component also renders ("Children render" is printed in the console).

How do I prevent children component from rendering when parent component is updating?

See code here: [I am a codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-r8fn5f?file=/src/Parent.jsx)

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Children from "./Children";

function Parent() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([{ name: "", price: "" }]);

  console.log("parent render");
  function handleNameChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleProductChange(index, product) {
    setProducts((prev) => {
      const newProducts = [...prev];
      newProducts[index] = product;
      return newProducts;
    });
  }

  function addAnotherProduct() {
    setProducts((prev) => {
      const newProducts = prev;
      return [...newProducts, { name: "", price: "" }];
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label>Category:</label>
      <input type="text" value={name} name="name" onChange={handleNameChange} />
      <br />
      {products.map((product, index) => {
        return (
          <Children
            key={index}
            name={product.name}
            price={product.price}
            handleProductChange={(product) =>
              handleProductChange(index, product)
            }
          />
        );
      })}

      <button onClick={addAnotherProduct}>Add another product</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

**Children Component**

```
import React from "react";

function Children(props) {
  const productName = props.name;
  const productPrice = props.price;

  const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    const newProduct = {
      name: productName,
      price: productPrice,
      [name]: value
    };
    console.log(newProduct);
    props.handleProductChange(newProduct);
  };

  console.log("Children Render");
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label>Product Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={productName}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange("name", event.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <label>Product Price:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={productPrice}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange("price", event.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Children);
```

I tried using `React.memo(children)` and `useCallback()` for `handleProductChange()` inside the parent component. However, both doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This function is different every time the component renders `(product) =>
              handleProductChange(index, product)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.memo` shallow compares current and previous props, and if one changes, it re-renders the component. In your case `handleProductChange` is generated on each parent render, and you also wrap in an arrow function, which generate a new function for each child.

[Working example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/working-react-memo-6smjsr?file=/src/Parent.jsx)

Wrap the function in `useCallback`:

```
const handleProductChange = useCallback((index, product) => {
  setProducts((prev) => {
    const newProducts = [...prev];
    newProducts[index] = product;
    return newProducts;
  });
}, []);
```

Avoid generating a new function for each child, and pass the `index` to the child:

```
<Children
  key={index}
  index={index}
  name={product.name}
  price={product.price}
  handleProductChange={handleProductChange}
/>
```

Call the `handleProducChange` with the `index` in the child:

```
const handleChange = (name, value) => {
  const newProduct = {
    name: productName,
    price: productPrice,
    [name]: value
  };
  console.log(newProduct);
  props.handleProductChange(props.index, newProduct);
};
```